# Flutter - Using provider and Firestore returning empty list

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, provider

I am trying to create a list using data from Firebase. I then want to pass this list to various parts of my app. When I run my code and test this element, the results show as an empty list. Here is my code. I first create an services class:

```
class OccasionServices {
  FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Future<List<String>> getAllOccasions(currentUser) async => _firestore
          .collection('collections')
          .doc(currentUser)
          .collection('occasions')
          .get()
          .then((snap) {
        List<String> allOccasions = [];
        snap.docs.forEach((snapshot) => snapshot
            .data()
            .entries
            .map((mapEntry) => allOccasions.add((mapEntry.value))));
        return allOccasions;
      });
}
```

I then create my Provider with ChangeNotifier:

```
class CollectionProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  User result = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  List<String> _allOccasions = [];
  OccasionServices _occasionServices = OccasionServices();

  CollectionProvider() {
    _getAllOccasions();
  }
  //getter
  List<String> get allOccasions => _allOccasions;

  void _getAllOccasions() async {
    _allOccasions = await _occasionServices.getAllOccasions(result.uid);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Then add the provider to my main.dart file:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: CollectionProvider()
        ),
        ],),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'My App',
        home: SignInPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

but when I come to use this list in another part of my app, I can only access an empty list:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final collectionProvider = Provider.of<CollectionProvider>(context);
  final collections = collectionProvider.allOccasions;
  print(collections);
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      title: Text('Viewer'),
    ),
    body: Container(
      child: Text('body'),
    ),
  );
}
```

Results:

```
I/flutter ( 4160): []
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Hi, can you print the return of _occasionServices.getAllOccasions, right before the `notifyListeners();`. For example by adding print("_getAllOccasions: $_allOccasions");

Comment: Hi dumazy, that also returns an empty list. That must mean there's a problem with my getAllOccasions function in OccasionServices. I will start investigating there.

Comment: update: there are document snapshots being returned from my firestore query. I think the problem might lie in the "map" part of the function.

Comment: Have you been able to fix the "map" part of your function? If not I can give you a solution.

Comment: Hi Chichebe, I haven't been able to fix it yet. Would really appreciated it if you could help me out.

Comment: Okay, from your document on Firebase what's the "key" to the String value you intend to add to your List<String>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try this approach:

```
class OccasionServices {
  FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Future<List<String>> getAllOccasions(currentUser) async => _firestore
          .collection('collections')
          .doc(currentUser)
          .collection('occasions')
          .get()
          .then((snap) =>
             snap.docs
              .map((doc) => doc.data().values.cast<String>())
              .expand((e) => e).toList()
          )
}
```

Step by step what does each thing do:

```
/// this will convert each doc in the docs List and return a new List of what is inside,
/// it will get all the values of the Map<String dynamic> returned by data() as a List<dynamic>
/// then you will cast them to String with .cast<String> (you have to be sure each value can be casted to String or it will throw)
.map((doc) => doc.data().values.cast<String>())
```

Before this you had a `QuerySnapshot` that has a List of `QueryDocumentSnapshot`, and each `QueryDocumentSnapshot` has a `Map<String, dynamic>`, so you had a `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` and what is inside of that list was transformed to a `List<String>`, so now you have a `List<List<String>>`, but you wanted a `List<String>`, not a nested List, so you  use the operator `expand` which can be used to flatten a list, it 'expands' what is inside so the result will be a `List<String>`.

As a final note if your documents can hold data different than String maybe you could try using `whereType<Map>()` instead of `cast()` to keep only the values that are String

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive answer. Definitely helped me understand the process better!